# How to specify "Service Name" in Oracle ODBC connection string

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, connection-string

I have an Excel macro that has an Oracle database connection. When I call the macro, it fills out user name and password but not service name. User has to enter service name manually every time.

How can I specify it in the connection string?

**Connection string:**

```
CN.ODBCConnection.Connection = _
"ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home2};" & _
"UID=" & inputUser & ";PWD=" & inputPassword & ";" & _
"HOST=" & inputHost & ";PORT=1521;DB=" & inputHost & ";" & _
"DefaultIsolationLevel=READUNCOMMITTED"
```

**Excel prompt:**

[image]

Comment: what is the service name is how is this a part of the connection string? See [ConnectionStrings for details](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

Comment: Already checked it out. There is a connection string in that website with "SERVICE_NAME=" parameter as Jimmy mentioned below but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. It's **DBQ**

New connection string:

```
CN.ODBCConnection.Connection = _
"ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home2};" & _
"DBQ=" & inputHost & ";UID=" & inputUser & ";PWD=" & inputPassword & ";" & _
"HOST=" & inputHost & ";PORT=1521;DB=" & inputHost & ";" & _
"DefaultIsolationLevel=READUNCOMMITTED"
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your driver, [check this out](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

But without a config file, you have to specify the options in the connection string.
Give this a try,

```
CN.ODBCConnection.Connection = _
"ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home2};" & _
"SERVICE_NAME=" & inputHost & ";UID=" & inputUser & ";PWD=" & inputPassword & ";" & _
"HOST=" & inputHost & ";PORT=1521;" & _
"DefaultIsolationLevel=READUNCOMMITTED"
```

Also, make sure inputHost should be used in both cases where it is currently.  One should be an instance of a server with the other being the database within it.

Comment: Good catch but it doesn't work. SERVICE parameter doesn't work neither. DB, HOST, and SERVICE NAME values are the same in my environment.

Comment: Aha, is it Oracle XE edition?  As I said, it's driver-dependent and I couldn't gather the driver from the original connection string.